# SharePoint Framework with Promise in extension

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, spfx, spfx-extensions, promises

I am trying to render header placeholder, but I am very new to the promise of SPFx.

Below line in my code runs before it returns any value. How can I await until it returns a string value?

```
this._topPlaceholder.domElement.innerHTML = this._getPlaceholderHtml();
```

My Code:

```
 private _renderPlaceholder(): void {
    if (!this._topPlaceholder) {
      this._topPlaceholder = this.context.placeholderProvider.tryCreateContent(
        PlaceholderName.Top,
        { onDispose: this._onDispose }
      );
    }

    // The extension should not assume that the expected placeholder is available.
    if (!this._topPlaceholder) {
      console.error('The expected placeholder (Top) was not found.');
      return;
    }

    // if it is available, and access to domElement, update contents
    if (this._topPlaceholder.domElement) {
      this._topPlaceholder.domElement.innerHTML = this._getPlaceholderHtml();
    }
  }

  private _getPlaceholderHtml(parentId?: number): string {
    let placeholderBody: string = '';
    this.service.getMenus(parentId).then((menuItems: IMenuListItem[]) => {
      if (menuItems && menuItems.length && menuItems.length > 0) {
        placeholderBody += '<ul>'
        menuItems.forEach((menutItem: IMenuListItem) => {
          placeholderBody += `<li><a href='${menutItem.Link}' target='${menutItem.Target}'>${menutItem.Title}</a>`
          if (menutItem.ParentId) {
            placeholderBody += this._getPlaceholderHtml(menutItem.ParentId) + '</li>'
          }
        })
        placeholderBody += '</ul>'
      }
    })
    return placeholderBody;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't test this code but it should be mostly right. It's enough to give you the idea of what you need to do.

There is an asynchronous call to `getMenus` inside the body of the `_getPlaceholderHtml` method so you need to update `_getPlaceholderHtml` to return a promise rather than a string. Once the call to `getMenus` has completed you can calculate the value of the `placeholderBody` variable and then you can use the resolve method to send the `placeholderBody` value to the caller of `_getPlaceholderHtml`.

```
private _getPlaceholderHtml(parentId?: number): Promise<string> {
    let promise = new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
        this.service.getMenus(parentId).then((menuItems: IMenuListItem[]) => {
            let placeholderBody: string = '';
            if (menuItems && menuItems.length && menuItems.length > 0) {
                placeholderBody += '<ul>'
                menuItems.forEach((menutItem: IMenuListItem) => {
                    placeholderBody += `<li><a href='${menutItem.Link}' target='${menutItem.Target}'>${menutItem.Title}</a>`
                    if (menutItem.ParentId) {
                        placeholderBody += this._getPlaceholderHtml(menutItem.ParentId) + '</li>'
                    }
                });
                placeholderBody += '</ul>'
            }
            resolve(placeholderBody);
        });
    });    

    return promise;
}
```

You then need to update the if statement that calls `_getPlaceholderHtml` to kick off the asynchronous process, wait for it to return the computed `placeholderBody`, and then update the user interface.

```
if (this._topPlaceholder.domElement) {
    this._getPlaceholderHtml().then((placeholderBody) => {
        this._topPlaceholder.domElement.innerHTML = placeholderBody;
    });
}
```